# Where can I find RGBA, color depth or compression settings?

Tags: rendering, video, color, compression

I'd like t get the usual *Output* panel back. I used Blender for some motion tracking and regular modeling stuff and here is how my *Output area* looks like now - no RGBA, compression slider, or color depth picker:

[image]

How should look like:

[image]

**Q:** How to get back to the default *Output* panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output options depend on the output format.
For *FFmpeg video*, just open the *Encoding* options to change the settings.

[image]